# How do I clean up my Memorized Payees in Quicken 2015?

Tags: quicken, spring-cleaning

My Payees in Quicken are a mess.  It seems like every transaction for the past 10 years has gotten an entry in there.  So how do I clean it up?  I can't delete them one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your list of memorized payees by going to `Tools->Memorized Payee List`

Find somebody who you know you haven't paid in a really long time, and remember them.

Close out of that window to return to the main window.

1. Click `Edit->Preferences`
2. In the Preferences Window in the tree pane click `Register->Data Entry and QuickFill`
3. Enter a value in `Remove memorized payees not used in the last N Months` textbox.
4. Click `OK`
5. Exit Quicken, and open it up again.

When Quicken loads up again, go back into `Tools->Memorized Payee List` and see if the Payee you haven't used in a long time is still there; the list should be considerably shorter.